# libmupdf gives error LNK2001 when using vcpkg

Tags: c++, vcpkg, mupdf

I installed libmupdf for windows x64 using vcpkg, but when I try to use anything from mupdf/fitz.h I get "fatal error LNK1120: 299 unresolved externals".

I have installed other libraries this way but this is the first to it.
to be honest I have no idea how to fix this.
any help would be amazing :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the MuPDF developers, and probably the one most concerned with building on windows. As such, I am unfamiliar with mupdf on vcpkg - it's not something we officially support, so anything I say here is possibly incorrect as it's not us that uploaded mupdf to there.

BUT... in the standard mupdf windows build, we build libmupdf.lib, which depends on libthirdparty.lib at least, and maybe other libs depending on the options used.

My advice would be to a) not install it using vcxproj unless the maintainers of that can give clear advice, and b) to build it from source.